# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tooltip')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tooltip

> **I'm using**
> React: "^17.0.2" version,
> typescript: "^4.4.3" version,
> material design: "^5.0.3" version
> in my project. I have the following error **TypeError** while I want to add a tooltip in my project:

**My Code Be Like:**

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={5}>
   <div className="contactSection">
      <div className="title_wrapper">
        <p>Contact us</p>
        <div className="border" />
      </div>

      <ul className="contact_lists">
        <li>
          <div className="icon_wrapper">
            <div className="circle" />
            <IoLocationOutline className="icon" />
          </div>

          <Tooltip title="See on Google Map" placement="top">
            <div className="contact_text">
              <a href="https://g.page/hamro-technology-pvt--ltd-?share" target="_blank">
                Kalanki, Kathmandu, Nepal
              </a>
            </div>
          </Tooltip>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

**It Throws following TypeError**
[image]

How to fix this problem??

Comment: Is it a custom `Tooltip` or MUI `Tooltip`?

Comment: show me your theme file please, I think it is missing the Zindex in that object

Comment: @NearHuscarl it's an MUI Theme

@PouyaAtaei theme is like as 
 ``

Comment: @PouyaAtaei please find My demo code in code sandbox :
[demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-chatterjee-c7id8?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: @NawarajJaishi There is no error in the codesandbox.

Comment: that's the thing I don't understand why it's show error?